# Time Validation with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate my forms. To validate a text input all I do is write `class="required"` in the attribute and it does the validation for me.

Now I am trying to validate an input where users will have to enter time( like 02:45:00 AM) but the plugin that I am using doesn't have any function for time validation. So, I have to build a custom validation for that but the problem is I have no knowledge of Jquery :(

Could you please show me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

For your information I need to build it for 12 hr time format

Comment: give some combo boxes to select the time to user then you can validate the esaily

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use jQuery Validators addMethod().

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {

$.validator.addMethod("time", function(value, element) {  
return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);  
}, "Please enter a valid time.");

    $("#login").validate({
            rules: {
                    time: "required time",
            },

     });

 });

 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="#">
  <h1>Time Validation</h1><br />
  <label for="time">Enter Time</label>
  <input id="time" name="time" type="text" value="" tabindex="1" /><br />
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" />
</form>
</body>
</html>​
```

Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e2DzT/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much- Martyhines. Would you please kindly tell me what code  to write here-   return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);                                          to make it validating for 12hr format (ex: 02:30 AM).* No 24 hr format is allowed (no- 21:20)

Comment: You could use `^(([0-1]?[0-2])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9])(a|p)m)?$` to validate for 12:34:56am or pm, or you could use `^(([0-1]?[0-2])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(a|p)m?$` for 12:34am or pm. Have a look at http://rubular.com/ to play with these regular expressions.

Comment: JSfiddle cleanup: http://jsfiddle.net/e2DzT/267/ for anyone who would like to toy around.

Comment: @user2019515 this is cleaner but it breaks if someone just enters the hours without `:` I think it should accept that with decimal or colon, or even if its left out