# jQuery DatePicker & DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web-applications, jquery-plugins

I have faced a little problem while trying to use this two jquery plugins. Hope someone can help me out with this.

The first plugin (DatePicker) I have used is the default one that comes with the jqueryui.
The second plugin (DateTimePicker) is the DateTimePicker from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

What I am trying to achieve is to have a user-defined date range like the sample provided in the jqueryui, with two textboxes (specify start date and end date) http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/date-range.html

While having another datetimepicker to allow user to select a datetime within the date specified above.

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/uyB52/1/

However, the issue here is that whenever I try to add in the datetimepicker javascript, the datepicker will not function properly. It will not be able to set the minimum date range as what it is suppose to be.

Have anyone encountered the same issue before? Can some one please advice me? I am still new to programming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the bug also occur if you only use the datepicker and not the datetimepicker?

Comment: @w4rumy Seems like if I were to not include the datetimepicker script, the datepicker will work normally as what I needed.

Comment: I seems like the datetimepicker plugin you are using interferes with jQuery UI's datepicker. Instead of trying to fix this somehow, I would suggest to either look for another datetime plugin or let the user simply input the time in input fields. Are you looking for a datetimepicker or a timepicker only?

Comment: @w4rumy Do you happen to have any datetimepicker plugin to recommend? Because I have been searching and trying for quite awhile, this is like the only plugin that I manage to get it "working" (to be able to appear as what it claims to be). I need a datetimepicker because I will need to only allow the user to choose within the date and time within the date he has chosen with the datepicker.

Comment: I made some suggestions in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your datetimepicker plugin interferes with jQuery UI (although it is supposed to be a working jQuery UI plugin). There may are possibilities to fix this issue, but I would recommend to use no or another plugin for picking the time (which works).

If you want to use a datetimepicker, you will have to search for different plugins and find out which one fits your needs best. I can not really recommend a plugin because it depends on your requirements.

But you could also go without a datetimepicker plugin and only use jQuery UI instead? Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyB52/7/

The idea is to use jQuery UI's datepicker for picking dates, and use dropdown boxes for choosing the time. You could also let the user input the time in an input field [and validate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294131/time-validation-with-jquery). Or, instead of dropdown boxes, [use the jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

Comment: Hey w4rumy, I have chosen to use your solution! Thanks for your help! Now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. You should convert string into Date as minDate and maxDate options take Date object.

```
$("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(selected_date))
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ap4sJ/)

Comment: The datepicker still behaves strange. Select one date from the first textbox, then a second date from the secon textbox. After that, select another date from the first again (which is still lower than the second one), and the date in the second one will change. Apart from that, according to the [jQuery UI datepicker documentation], min and max get a "selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat", so why does giving a String not work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like what @w4rumy said was true, the datepicker still behaves strangely. Can you please help me out with this?