# Validate a time from the <input type=“time”…>

Tags: javascript, php, validation, time

I would like to validate the field for the input type of time. Currently, I am trying to use the javascript method to validate the field(s).

This is the code that I have used.

My current time format is example: 12:00 pm

Just wondering on how I can validate the fields for the input type of time. I am not sure on how to achieve on the validation. I was hoping if I can get some tips on how to validate it.

Comment: if you don't mind using jquery and jquery-validate you can inspire here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294131/time-validation-with-jquery

Comment: _"This is the code that I have used"_ I can't see any code, does that mean you haven't written any?

Comment: The value of a input type of time must be 'A valid partial-time as defined in [RFC 3339]' see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html. So it can not be an invalid time. But note that not all browsers support the type, check http://caniuse.com/input-datetime for support.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to validate the time format/value/input would be to add an event listener. Either on the `change` event, or before submitting the data to the server. A simple regex would be more than enough:

```
var timeVal = document.querySelector('#timeInput').value;
if (timeVal.match(/\d+:\d+/))
    console.log(timeVal + ' is a valid time-format');
else
    return false;//or preventDefault + stopPropagation() on event
```

## [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2f9E3/)

Side-note:
the `time` input-type is not universally supported yet, [far from it](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime). It'd be better if you use a plugin of sorts, or use some selects, and process their values using JS.

Comment: hi, what value will this POST as to the server? a decimal or time, and how to ensure it does not roll over into 99 mins etc

Comment: All post data is string, always

Comment: To ensure values don't excede 59, use html 5 inputs, and/Or add further client and server-side validation, same as always

Comment: I noticed this does not work with firefox, thanks for posting, I upvoted. I was trying [jqueryValidation](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation) plugin but could not find the time validation rule, any chance you could show how to bind your rule to that

Comment: It's an old answer, so it's probably best to check more recent answers. I'm using my phone atm, so if I remember this exchange by tomorrow, I might take another look. Best of luck meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', function()
{
document.getElementById("foobar").style.border = "solid 1px #ccc";
if(checkValid()){
  alert('OK');
}else{
  //alert('Invalid');
document.getElementById("foobar").style.border = "solid 1px red";  
}
    
}, false);


function checkValid(){
var timeVal = document.querySelector('#foobar').value;
if (timeVal.match(/\d+:\d+/))
   return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input type='time' id='foobar'>
    <input type='button' value='test' id='check'>
```

Answer (score -3):

Do you expect from user to type the time or what?!i mean usually in time and date stuff it`s better to use components.any way javascript is best tool for such a thing but i think you could use RegExp in javascript as a good solution

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (simply because it doesn't answer the question)

Comment: @Ariyous I am expecting that the user will input a time.